# Get name of assembly without version and other details

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, assembly-name

I am getting the name of an assembly as follows:

```
String fullName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CP.Proj.ILogger)).FullName;
```

And I get the following:

> CP.Proj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Is there a way to get only the assembly name `"CP.Proj"`, without the version and other infos?

Comment: Did you look at the return type of [`Assembly.GetAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [available properties and methods of that type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `typeof(CP.Proj.ILogger).ToString();`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to get the [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object of that assembly through the [Assembly.GetName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CP.Proj.ILogger)).GetName().Name
```

If the assembly is the one which is calling that method you can use:

```
string name = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

or even create an utility method

```
public static string GetAssemblyShortName()
{
    return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this ,

```
**1**
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name


**2**
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name;
```